# Dynamically update hyperkink link text with Javascript

Tags: jquery

I wish to change the text of the hyperlink dynamically, and trigger the change with Javascript.

I have html:

```
<a id="HyperlinkID" href="#" >Original text</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$("a#HyperlinkID").text() = "Text changed";
```

That does not seem to work.

What is the right way to change the text?

Comment: You also don't need the a before the # in the selector. Selecting just using the ID is the best way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$("a#HyperlinkID").html("Text changed");
```

Comment: alternatively, if you wanted to go vanilla javascript, you could do: document.getElementById('HyperlinkID').innerHTML = "Text changed";

Comment: Is there any difference between using html() or text() ? Both seem to work fine...

Comment: @tucson: Using `text`, the expectation is that you're providing *text* and so it will escape `<`, `>`, and `&` for you, replacing them with the appropriate entities. Using `html`, the expectation is that you're providing *HTML*, and so you might (for instance) be giving it `html("This is a <em>really</em> good link")`.

Comment: @tucson from the jQuery documentation for `text()` "Unlike the .html() method, .text() can be used in both XML and HTML documents."

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a#HyperlinkID").text("Text changed");
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("a#HyperlinkID").text("Text changed");`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
$("a#HyperlinkID").text("Text changed");
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$("#HyperlinkID").text("Text changed");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('a#HyperlinkID').text("your replacement text goes here");
```

this may help,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it slightly simpler and faster, if you're interested:

```
$("#HyperlinkID").text("Text changed");
```

When you specify the id of an element, you don't need anything else.  That's as efficient as it gets.

Otherwise, this is the same as everyone else has suggested.